# Tool to generate monthly traffic reports for IIS sites?

Tags: iis, traffic, reporting

We want to calculate a monthly total of uploads and downloads for each of our IIS sites.

Can we generate this from the IIS logs?

Thanks,

Ashley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think either [Analog](http://www.analog.cx/) or [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net) would be able to give you what you require

**Edited to add:** Re-reading your question - Do you just want to know about uploads\download of certain files? Or total traffic transferred for your website(s)?

Comment: Thanks Ben, we want just the total traffic for billing purposes.

Comment: No worries, glad it was of use!

There are many options in both tools' configuration files, so you should be able to get the data out that you're after